# Validate form using JQuery (without dedicated lib)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have an HTML form containing a table presenting (among others) two columns with a checkbox and an input text field. The user first checks the checkbox, then modifies the value in the input text field. Before submitting this form I would like to validate the user inputs.

I implemented this validation function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var error = false;
$('#form-id').submit(function (event) {
var pattern = /^[0-9]+$/;
alert(pattern); // 1st
var error = false;
$('#form-id input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
        if(sThisVal === 'on') {
         var field = $(this).closest('td').siblings()
                                .find("input[type=text]")[0];

         var value = field.value;
         alert(value); // 2nd
         var ok = pattern.test(value);
         alert(ok); // 3rd
         if( ! ok) {
            error = true;
            field.addClass('red-border');   
         } // if on ok
        } // if checked
      }); // foreach checkbox
    return ! error;
    });
```

Everything is ok till the 3rd alert. Then it fails on `addClass` with this message:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function 
               (evaluating 'field.addClass('red-border')')
```

So field is `undefined` but it was ok when I read its value.

I am not expert at all in Javascript or JQuery but after reading the docs I cannot understand why this happens.

Comment: alert(value); What does it return?

Comment: It shows the correct values, i.e. the values I was expecting to read. That's why I say that it works ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these lines

```
var field = $(this).closest('td')
                   .siblings()
                   .find("input[type=text]");//jQuery object
var value = field[0].value; // field[0] is a native HTML element
```

The error was that you tried to `addClass`, *a jQuery method*, to a native HTML element

See this fiddle for explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/tH5xc/

Comment: Thank you very much. After looking at your solution and comments I feel stupid (may be I should make this feeling mine and keep it every single minute, but I prefer not  to). Actually I thought that was the reason but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

`if( ! ok) {` should be `if( !ok) {` without space!

And also,

`return ! error;` should be `return error = !error;`

Comment: two upvotes for this? please take down the answer. its wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/3EAUh/

Comment: I think C-link considered too basic my question and decided to pull my leg.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a jquery object try:

```
if(!ok) {
       error = true;
       field[0].addClass('red-border');    
    }
```

instead of:

```
if( ! ok) {
       error = true;
       field.addClass('red-border');    
    }
```